# how can I get image to show on roku video player

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm trying to get a image to show on roku video player while the video is playing but it does not work. here is my code:

```
function player(video_id as String,stream as String,streamTitle as String,subtitle_url as String,position as String)

    print "play: "+stream
    p = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    video = CreateObject("roVideoScreen")
    video.setMessagePort(p)

    videoclip = CreateObject("roAssociativeArray")
    videoclip.StreamBitrates = [0]
    videoclip.StreamUrls = [stream]

    di = CreateObject("roDeviceInfo")
    if di.GetDisplayType() = "HDTV" then 
        videoclip.streamqualities=["HD"]
    else
        videoclip.streamqualities=["SD"]
    end if

    videoclip.PlayStart=position.toint()

    videoclip.StreamFormat = "hls"
    videoclip.switchingstrategy="full-adaptation"
    videoclip.Title = streamTitle
    if subtitle_url<>invalid
        videoclip.SubtitleUrl = subtitle_url
    end if

    lastSavedPos   = 0
    statusInterval = 10
    nowpos=0


    video.SetPositionNotificationPeriod(10)
    video.SetContent(videoclip)
    video.show()
    showImageCanvas()
    while true
        msg = wait(0, video.GetMessagePort())
        if type(msg) = "roVideoScreenEvent"
            if msg.isScreenClosed() then 'ScreenClosed event
                return "incomplete"
                exit while                
            else if msg.isFullResult()
                SetXtraData(video_id,"0")
                return "completed"
            else if msg.isResumed()
                SetXtraData(video_id,nowpos.tostr())
            else if msg.isPlaybackPosition() then

                nowpos = msg.GetIndex()
                if nowpos > 120
                    if abs(nowpos - lastSavedPos) > statusInterval
                        lastSavedPos = nowpos
                        SetXtraData(video_id,nowpos.tostr())               
                    end if
                end if
            else if msg.isRequestFailed()
                showMessage("Information","Something went wrong while we tried to play the video")
            else
                print "Unknown event: "; msg.GetType(); " msg: "; msg.GetMessage()
                 showImageCanvas()
            endif
        end if
    end while
end function





Sub showImageCanvas()
    canvasItems = [
        { 
            url:"http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg"
            TargetRect:{x:189,y:300,w:100,h:100}
        }
    ]

   canvas = CreateObject("roImageCanvas")
   port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
   canvas.SetMessagePort(port)
   'Set opaque background
   'canvas.SetLayer(0, {Color:"#FF000000", CompositionMode:"Source"})
   canvas.SetRequireAllImagesToDraw(true)
   canvas.SetLayer(1, canvasItems)
   canvas.Show()
   while(true)
       msg = wait(0,port)
       if type(msg) = "roImageCanvasEvent" then
           if (msg.isRemoteKeyPressed()) then
               i = msg.GetIndex()
               print "Key Pressed - " ; msg.GetIndex()
               if (i = 2) then
                   ' Up - Close the screen.
                   canvas.close()
               end if
           else if (msg.isScreenClosed()) then
               print "Closed"
               return
           end if
       end if
   end while
End Sub
```

I keep placing this `showImageCanvas()` everywhere to try and get it to work, but it does not work. Please help.

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: in what way doesn't it work? skimming the code, it seems it will show image canvas till one exits with Back, then will play video (till one presses a button?), then show image canvas again till Back pressed? Sounds as if it will show the canvas, just not at the same time with the video because of the way event loops are written

Comment: yes that is the problem i am having it will not play the video and  show image at the same time

Comment: My answer can sound kind of silly but - just don't do that then :). I mean it is your code that stays in event loop until one closes the roImageCanvas with a Back button. Just don't do that :). You can handle multiple type of events from multiple components in one loop, often via the same roMessagePort. Btw you may get more attention if you ask the question in the Roku dev.forum at https://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34

Comment: Rewrite your code using scenegraph and it will be a thousand times easier